# If $U$ is a linear isometry on $H$, then $\frac1n\left\|(1-U^n)x\right\|_H\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, isometry

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space and $U$ be a linear isometry on $H$. Trivial question: How can we show that $$\frac1n\left\|(1-U^n)x\right\|_H\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag1$$ for all $x\in H$? Can't figure out the trick for the moment. Maybe writing $1-U^n=1-U^{n-1}+U^{n-1}-U^n$ so that $\left\|(1-U^n)x\right\|_H\le\left\|(1-U^{n-1})x\right\|_H+\left\|(1-U)x\right\|_H$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint - use the operator norm. The norm of an isometry is $1$, and so you get (using the triangle inequality):

$$\frac{1}{n}||1-U^n||\leq \frac{1}{n}(||1||+||U||^n)=\frac{2}{n}$$

Comment: Oops! Sure, you're right. Just a quick related question. $U$ is an isometry and hence $UH$ is closed. So, $(1-U)$ is closed as well, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, this is due to the closed graph theorem

Comment: But the closed graph theorem implies that the *graph* of a closed linear operator between Banach spaces is closed. This does *not* imply that its range is closed as well. Am I missing something?